# Debian & Blackmagic Davinci Resolve

Tags: video, video-editor

Anyone got Davinci Resolve to run on Debian?
Version 15.x installs great without error on debian but it crashes upon startup.
I would like to hear from anyone who runs it with Debian, what video cards you are using etc.

for the record, here is the terminal output of the crash.

```
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve
ActCCMessage Already in Table: Code= c005, Mode= 13, Level=  1, CmdKey= -1, Option= 0
ActCCMessage Already in Table: Code= c006, Mode= 13, Level=  1, CmdKey= -1, Option= 0
ActCCMessage Already in Table: Code= c007, Mode= 13, Level=  1, CmdKey= -1, Option= 0
ActCCMessage Already in Table: Code= 2282, Mode=  0, Level=  0, CmdKey= 8, Option= 0
PnlMsgActionStringAdapter Already in Table: Code= 615e, Mode=  0, Level=  0, CmdKey= -1, Option= 0
log4cxx: No appender could be found for logger (UI).
log4cxx: Please initialize the log4cxx system properly.
15.2.4 (#006) Linux/Clang
Main thread starts: 99B99AC0
resolve: AppConfig.cpp:171: void AppConfig::LoadAllSiteInfo(): Assertion `m_SiteEnabledIdx > 0' failed.


==========[CRASH DUMP]==========
Please send this to support:

# TIME Wed Mar  6 10:36:48 2019 - Uptime 00:00:00 (hh:mm:ss)
# PROGRAM_NAME DaVinci Resolve v15.2.4.006 (Linux/Clang)

/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x467c199]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x18b0893]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x110e0) [0x7f72800a90e0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0xcf) [0x7f727e11afff]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x16a) [0x7f727e11c42a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x2be67) [0x7f727e113e67]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x2bf12) [0x7f727e113f12]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x189ddf0]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x189c5c6]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x189be98]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x1d58051]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x1d57dc4]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x18af69e]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x1897944]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf1) [0x7f727e1082e1]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x189679d]
Signal Number = 6

================================
resolve: AppConfig.cpp:171: void AppConfig::LoadAllSiteInfo(): Assertion `m_SiteEnabledIdx > 0' failed.


==========[CRASH DUMP]==========
Please send this to support:

# TIME Wed Mar  6 10:36:48 2019 - Uptime 00:00:00 (hh:mm:ss)
# PROGRAM_NAME DaVinci Resolve v15.2.4.006 (Linux/Clang)

/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x467c199]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x18b0893]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x110e0) [0x7f72800a90e0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0xcf) [0x7f727e11afff]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x16a) [0x7f727e11c42a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x2be67) [0x7f727e113e67]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x2bf12) [0x7f727e113f12]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x189ddf0]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x189c5c6]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x189be98]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x18d0e0d]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x18b0ade]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x110e0) [0x7f72800a90e0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0xcf) [0x7f727e11afff]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x16a) [0x7f727e11c42a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x2be67) [0x7f727e113e67]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x2bf12) [0x7f727e113f12]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x189ddf0]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x189c5c6]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x189be98]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x1d58051]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x1d57dc4]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x18af69e]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x1897944]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf1) [0x7f727e1082e1]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x189679d]
Signal Number = 6

================================
Aborted
```

Comment: I tried it on Ubuntu and had the same problem, didn't test it any further

Comment: Dual 1080 titan black.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running on Nvidia graphics card, you need non-free nvidia drivers (not noveau drivers), e.g.:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-450
```

Reboot system and check `dkms`

```
$ sudo dkms status
nvidia, 450.80.02, 5.4.0-51-generic, x86_64: installed
```